# How to implement a custom DataStoreFactory for use with Google APIs using OAuth2?

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to implement a custom `DataStoreFactory` as mentioned in the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#data_store) so that I can authenticate with Google APIs and store my access/refresh tokens in my database, but I can't find any documentation or examples of a custom implementation e.g.

```
// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
             .setDataStoreFactory(new MyCustomDatastoreFactory() )
             .setAccessType("offline")
             .build();
```

If I implement the `DataStoreFactory` interface, it gives me one method to implement:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;

public class MyCustomDatastoreFactory implements DataStoreFactory {

    @Override
    public <V extends Serializable> DataStore<V> getDataStore(String arg0) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

}
```

The `DataStore` object has several methods that need to be implemented, but I'm not sure where and how exactly I need to use this to retrieve and store my credentials:

```
new DataStore<Serializable>() {

    @Override
    public DataStore<Serializable> clear() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(String arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Serializable arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public DataStore<Serializable> delete(String arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable get(String arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataStoreFactory getDataStoreFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataStore<Serializable> set(String arg0, Serializable arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Serializable> values() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
};
```

There is also `DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener` class, but do I need to implement that and associate it with my `DataStoreFactory` or `DataStore` so that it will automatically update my DB with new tokens?

Comment: you can try to use `MemoryDataStoreFactory` to simplify your work.

Comment: @min I never did actually figure this out, but as a workaround I ended up using `FileDataStoreFactory` loaded from the local file system.

Comment: I found a couple articles but I haven't tried them yet:

https://medium.com/@dirkvranckaert/google-authentication-with-jpa-f1c78d386c45

https://mlescaille.medium.com/using-a-db-and-jpa-as-data-store-for-google-authentication-e1780b22e772